# How to format code?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Whatever the link they have here to put before code does not work, it always tries to execute it. How can I post some code so it just displays?

Comment: Try clicking on the [yellow question mark rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and read it. If you still have questions and problems understanding what it says don't hesitate to ask them on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm not sure how much of that was actual edit collisions and how much of it was just sequential editing. Somehow, I managed to start both of my edits after the previous submission, though, so there was no overwrite.

Comment: @Grace I collided with yours, but we both deleted the second half of the post so my revision didn't bring it back. Looks like you tried to edit your revision within the window to change tags, so it pushed with the same revision message

Comment: @Michael That indeed happened - I was trying to pretend that I included the markdown tag in the first place. I somehow did that while unknowingly retaining your title and post body, which is the more humorous point. Talk about exact timing.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight your code, and then press the  {} image for code sample (or ctrl+k).

Your code will appear in the bottom of your screen (the preview) in a grey box, then you know you did it correctly. That box is above the "Post your answer" button. Like this:

```
<?php

echo "hello stackoverflow";

?>
```

Sounds like you're having a bad day, and I hope it improves. :)

Comment: protip: use `<kbd>{}</kbd>` to further illustrate it's a button above the body element.

Answer (score 2):

Hi,

Enter your code, select it and then press Ctrl-K